# peer to peer communication between mobile app and pc browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, network-programming, browser

I am working on a project where i need my mobile application to talk to my web browser on a pc, where both devices are connected over wifi. The app would send data which would be received by the computer browser followed by some client side code execution. The browser then may send some feedback.

My initial approach is to make the app talk to an endpoint which in turn talks to client side of the browser (`javascript`).

What could be the best approach to do this ?

**Update**

I am not sure if `Socket.io` is a possible solution since it requires a server to be hosted. Is it possible to solve this using sockets ?

Comment: it would be remarkably more helpful if you could SIMPLY STATE WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO DO.  For example, is thus a car racing game?  Is it a text message system? Does it involve images?  Please just state the goal!

Comment: Dupe .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975622/peer-to-peer-between-desktop-and-mobile-app

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you're trying to hack together two things that are very different. A browser, in most cases, is just that - a web viewer. Lately there is more and more client-side computing being done for web browsing, but without something like a Java applet, you seem to be trying to make a client <- server relationship out of a client-client relationship. If you need the PC to view information from your phone, there are much simpler ways to do this, and vice-versa.

Comment: Looks like pubnub is the solution for now, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've now edited your question **to mention P2P**. That's quite hard to achieve PHONE TO BROWSER (i.e., by hard I mean 6 to 12 man-months of work - and/or plain not possible). However in MOST situations you can instantly (ie "one line of code on each platform") resolve the problem by using a service like pubnub.  Much as nobody has back-ends anymore and everything is just done with parse.com or game center, networking like you mention is now just done with pubunb (or any competitor).

This is an extremely common use case problem - and everyone just uses PubNub as mentioned below or one of its competitors.

---

These days it couldn't be easier, just use pubnub.com

It's the world's biggest data-messaging service for a reason!

There's essentially no other realistic approach, it's so simple - a few lines of code.

[image]

Comment: This would mean that both the devices would connect over the internet. I am not experienced with network technologies. Is there an alternative approach where both devices can communicate via sockets ?

Comment: Basically no.  Fortunately it's one line of code in pubnub.

Comment: @JoeBlow This isn't an attack on PubNub; I haven't used it and I don't know much about it. However, the OP asks for a *P2P* solution, which PubNub is *not*. PubNub also isn't free, which at least makes me wonder if you're affiliated with them (although that's neither here nor there when it comes to correctness, I suppose). But when you say "there's essentially no other realistic approach", maybe I just need you to clarify. Seeing as you're pitching a solution that doesn't match the question, what approach in particular is PubNub the only realistic approach to?

Comment: Little clarification, i had editted the question and added the term "peer to peer" but i always was looking for a P2P solution anyways. Sorry if i have caused any confusion, but `pubnub` looks like a way out, although i'll keep searching for a better solution. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Finally went ahead with this, Thanks!

Comment: Well yes, there's no other way to do it  :)  Hope it helps

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it sounds like a marketing pitch, and does not give an actual technical solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

So short answer would be: A real peer-to-peer (P2P) communication is currently not possible with all browsers. So instead you have the following options:

1. App + Server with a WebUI (maybe)
2. App + Chrome App (Chrome Apps can start an web server, see http://www.devworx.in/news/misc/chrome-apps-can-now-run-a-web-server-135711.html)
3. App + WebApp with Plugin (Flash, Silverlight or Java)

I personally would prefer solution 1.

Answer (score 2):

You need a server. If you consider this problem strictly from the typical firewall point of view, a PC or a mobile device are going to ignore connections unless they initiate the connection themselves. So neither the PC nor the mobile device can start a connection with the other.

My understanding is that web browsers do not support standard sockets within javascript. You can use the analagous websocket, but sockets and websockets are not directly compatible.

You can setup a simple server on the PC, and have this server relay messages between the mobile device and the PC browser. Both the mobile device and the PC browser connect to the server. This is basically what an external service will do for you.

Comment: Right. You essentially "can not" socket from a browser: As of 2014 there are essentially experimental solutions, that will work with a few browsers in certain situations (hypery2k has outlined these). Just as mattm says, you need a server. Regarding making a server: it does seem almost incredible, in this era, one would build a service to do this from scratch (assuming you have massive, incredibly redundant, multi-homing world-wide hardware on tap) rather than just using one of the everyday services available for this, which are used in 100% of use cases!

Answer (score 1):

PeerJS is what you're looking for:

http://peerjs.com

Comment: That looks like a great solution on the Browser side, hyper - BUT do you know what can be done on the iOS/Android side with this?  Cheers!

Comment: Article on WebRTC etc http://blogging.alastair.is/webrtc-datachannels-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-flap-my-arms/

Comment: Clicking around, http://peerjs.com/examples it would appear that PeerJS only works on limited browsers.  Whenever I click on the examples it just says "not supported"

Comment: you can use WebRTC with cordova (https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc) It supports iOS and Android, but you still need a signaling server...

Comment: I see, so it's not for native apps. Cheers!

Comment: you can use the native code from the cordova plugin above ;)